# Obtain the long Post URL from the ID in the Database Table

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

My site has a url `(example.com/folder/index.php?id=22)`

The above URL displays the post id 22. Here's another important part:

```
|-------|-----------|-------------------|-------------------|
|   id  |   user    |       title       |       url         |
|-------|-----------|-------------------|-------------------|
|   22  |   Admin   |   My Title Posts  |   my_title_post   |
|       |           |                   |                   |
|-------|-----------|-------------------|-------------------|

include_once 'dbconnect.php';

$query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=".$_GET['id']);
$Row=$query->fetch_array();

echo $Row['user'];
echo $Row['title'];
echo $Row['url'];
```

**Results:**

-Admin

-My Title Posts

-my_title_post

I'm trying to hide `$_GET['id'];` By adding `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^newfolder/(.*) folder/index.php?id=$1
```

My new URL is : `example.com/newfolder/22`

But, this is still not quite right. I am trying to display a long post URL in the URL section, not the ID.
So I mean, how to make the URL become:

```
example.com/newfolder/my_title_post
```

I have changed the SQL to:
`"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE url=".$_GET['id']` But the server can not handle the request.

I have also tried to change the Primary Key in the database url column but the request is rejected. Here I set it to Unique, but it still did not work.

Is it possible to do that?
If anyone knows, I accept suggestions via Cpanel, htaccess, SQL or something else. Thanks ..

Comment: Do you know what would happen if someone goes to this url: example.com/folder/index.php?id=1%20OR%201%3D1. Read about SQL Injection - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: @lloiacono I do not know what you mean

Comment: _“I have changed the SQL to: "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE url=".$_GET['id'] But the server can not handle the request.”_ – that sounds more like you can not handle database errors correctly yet - which is therefor what you should go read up on first of all. _Ask_ the database, what problem it had with your statement, so you can fix it.

Comment: @lloiacono Oh yes. I accidentally cut the code to become narrow. The original code uses real_escape_string

Comment: I was trying to show you that your code is susceptible to SQL Injection, you should never use user input directly into your queries. In my example above your query would then look like this: SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=1 OR 1=1; Which will show all records, or it could be even worst an attacker could drop your database for instance

Comment: [`FallbackResource`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource) seems to be one way around this. Note that http://serverfault.com might be better able to help.

Comment: @CBroe I mean the php script, initially using `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id` To retrieve data by ID. Then I change to URL to retrieve data by URL

Comment: I know what you want to achieve. I was trying to get you do do some proper basic debugging to find out why what you tried did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `my_title_post` is a string. But your query is treated it an integer. Quote the `$_GET['id']` to treat it a string.

```
"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE url='".$_GET['id'] . "'";
```

Also it is better to use parameter binding to prevent [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). At least you need to use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) to prevent it.

Comment: I have to say thank you very much for your answer. This works. :)